# ASP.NET cookies missing in HttpContext.Request.Cookies. Comma vs semi-colon separated cookies from Chrome/IE

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, cookies

I'm observing an issue where I make a request to my server and inspect the `HttpContext.Request.Cookies` collection to be different in Chrome vs IE.

My process is as follows:

1. Launch a new inPrivate browser for IE, go to site url
2. Observe  `HttpContext.Request.Cookies` to have **three** values, *siteLang*, *siteDir*, *isNative*
3. Observe the value of each cookie to respectively be:

   - `HttpContext.Request.Cookies["siteDir"].Value`  == "ltr"
   - `HttpContext.Request.Cookies["siteLang"].Value` == "en-US"
   - `HttpContext.Request.Cookies["isNative"].Value` == true
4. Launch a new incognito browser for Chrome, go to site url
5. Observe `HttpContext.Request.Cookies` to have **one** value, *siteDir*
6. Observe the value of `HttpContext.Request.Cookies["siteDir"].Value` to be *"ltr, siteLang=en-US, isNative=true"*

---

I have also observed `HttpContext.Request.Headers["Cookie"]` to contain the following values dependent on browser:

- siteLang=en-US; siteDir=ltr; isNative=true       // IE
- siteDir=ltr, siteLang=en-US, isNative=true       // Chrome

---

So it appears Chrome is comma separating my cookies and IE is using semi-colons and Mvc can't figure out how to deal with the commas. Has anyone else seen this? I feel like this issue should be incredibly widespread if my diagnosis is correct. Any input is greatly appreciated.

### EDIT

I've looked into the ASP.NET source and found the following code snippet in HttpRequest.cs (found here: [http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpRequest.cs][1]):

```
while (i < l) {
    // find next ';' (don't look to ',' as per 91884)
    j = i;
    while (j < l) {
        ch = s[j];
        if (ch == ';')
            break;
        j++;
    }
    // create cookie form string
    ...{continued}
```

Any ideas how I get information on 91884 to understand why they are ignoring comma separated cookies?

Answer (score 0):

I am noticing odd behavior like this right now too.
But looking at Fiddler, the cookie list is actually sent as ';' separated..

I am on Windows 10. I've tried rolling back my commit history to several months back but keep running into the issue.

The issue seems to especially happen on SSL. Can it be OS/WindowsUpdate related?

Comment: Important note: When I have fiddler turned on, I see totally different results, the cookie operates as expected. I am also on Win 10, will investigate that further

Comment: I can confirm, it is indeed when Fiddler is in the mix it changes up.

Comment: As a dirty workaround in debug/local mode I came up with:
var cookieHeader = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Cookie"];
if (cookieHeader != null)
   HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.Set("Cookie", cookieHeader.Replace(",", ";"));